# check if string contains any of the elements of a stringarray (vb net)

Tags: vb.net, string, compare, contains, arrays

I´ve got a little problem. At the end of a programm it should delete a folder.

In ordern to deny deletion of a folder, which directory contains a certain word, I wanted to check if a string (the directory.fullname.tostring) contains any of the elements which are stored in a string array.
The string array contains strings stating the exception words.

This is how far I got and I know that the solution is the other way round than stated here:

```
If Not stackarray.Contains(dir.FullName.ToString) Then

                Try
                    dir.Delete()
                    sw.WriteLine("deleting directory " + dir.FullName, True)
                    deldir = deldir + 1
                Catch e As Exception
                    'write to log
                    sw.WriteLine("cannot delete directory " + dir.ToString + "because there are still files in there", True)
                    numbererror = numbererror + 1
                End Try
            Else
                sw.WriteLine("cannot delete directory " + dir.ToString + "because it is one of the exception directories", True)
            End If
```

Comment: `I wanted to check if a string (the directory.fullname.tostring) contains any of the elements which are stored in a string array` .. such as what ?

Comment: those elements are folder paths. like "D:\stuff_not_to_delete".

Comment: Your code not worked as expected ? .. which part ?

Comment: The first line didn´t worked as excpected. I should work the other way round. The intended way was: the programm should check if the string of the directory.fullname contains any of the elements and if it does, it should do nothing, otherwise it should delete the folder if possible. now it checks, if the array contains the dir.fullname string and that has not the intended effect...

Comment: I think it should be enough with `If Not stackarray.Contains(dir.FullName) Then` ..

Comment: In the end you were right, got confused by my own confusion. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of checking to see if the array contains the full path, do it the other way around.  Loop through all the items in the array and check if the path contains each one, for instance:

```
Dim isException As Boolean = False
For Each i As String In stackarray
    If dir.FullName.ToString().IndexOf(i) <> -1 Then
        isException = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
If isException Then
    ' ...
End If
```

Or, if you want to be more fancy, you can use the Array.Exists method to do it with less lines of code, like this:

```
If Array.Exists(stackarray, Function(x) dir.FullName.ToString().IndexOf(x) <> -1) Then
    ' ...
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
foldersToDelete.Any(Function(folder) dir.ToLower.Contains(folder.ToLower)
```

You can check more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0)