# Using If statement to verify if string value is in an array of strings

Tags: .net, vb.net, if-statement

I have a string and an array of strings. I was wondering if it is possible to use an If statement in order to return a boolean value if the string contains a value from the array.

The code below doesn't work properly. `Contains` can only take in one value as far as I can see. Is there a better way to do this without having to use a loop?

```vb
Dim FilePath As String = "C:\Users\Downloads\Test.jpg"
Dim GetExtension As String = FilePath.Substring(FilePath.Length - 3)
Dim FileExtensionArray() As String = {".png", ".jpg", ".tif"}

If GetExtension.Contains(FileExtension) = True Then
   ' Code
Else
   ' Code
End If
```

Comment: Have a look at this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952971/check-if-string-contains-any-of-the-elements-of-a-stringarray-vb-net

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check if string contains any of the elements of a stringarray (vb net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952971/check-if-string-contains-any-of-the-elements-of-a-stringarray-vb-net)

Comment: That is a good solution to my problem. However, I was wondering if it was possible to do without a loop :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a couple of things to note about your code:

```
Dim GetExtension As String = FilePath.Substring(FilePath.Length - 3)
Dim FileExtensionArray() As String = {".png", ".jpg", ".tif"}
```

GetExtension now contains `jpg` but your arrays are `.jpg`. There's some built-in help already available for file extensions:

```
IO.Path.GetExtension(FilePath)
```

Lastly, your `If .... Then` test is the wrong way round. With a couple of simple adjustments I'd use this:

```
    Dim FilePath As String = "C:\Users\Downloads\Test.jpg"
    Dim FilePathExtension As String = IO.Path.GetExtension(FilePath)
    Dim FileExtensionArray As String() = {".png", ".jpg", ".tif"}

    If FileExtensionArray.Contains(FilePathExtension) Then
        'yes
    Else
        'no
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could convert FileExtensionArray in a string with the function Join:

```
 GetExtensionsJoin= String.Join( "-", FileExtensionArray)
```

After that, you could use the method "contains" to check if string contains the extension.

```
 GetExtensionsJoin.contains(GetExtension)
```

Comment: This will return `true` for a wrong reasons. For example when file extension is a substring of any of allowed extensions.